# Dynamic Island and iPhone14 Pro simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, simulator, dynamic-island

I saw that 9to5mac has done a [brilliant article](https://9to5mac.com/2022/09/08/iphone-14-pro-how-dynamic-island-works/) covering dynamic island and how it behaves in day-to-day uses.

Wondering if there is any chance to test dynamic island on  iPhone14 Pro simulator with Xcode RC candidate as they do. I tried but seems that the dynamic island zone on simulator is not reacting to anything. Any suggestions is welcome.

Comment: Did you try to dag and drop an json apps file on it?

Comment: not sure to understand your comment. what's a json apps file?

Comment: look at this doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification

Answer (score 1):

Same here, I am also excited to try it but seems like it's not responds in simulator. I tried playing music and touching it but didn't worked!

Comment: Yes, I do agree, In my app, the Navigation bar items are behind the Island.

Answer (score 1):

14/11/2022
As the latest update of Xcode, now iPhone 14 Pro & 14 Pro Max simulators support "Dynamic Island".

You can open a YouTube video with the simulator using safari and when you exit safari you will be able to control the video with "Dynamic Island".

Comment: it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework called ActivityKit which will make the dynamic island available in simulator but is not currently released as of now at the time of writing this answer, it'll be released later this year(But it is available in beta version).

See the link below~

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=hi37aek8